# Is there a way to enable paging in node js REPL

Tags: node.js, less, read-eval-print-loop

I would like to see paging when I have long outputs in node js REPL.

Is that possible, how?

Answer (score 1):

[Vorpal.js](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) is a Node module that looks like it would do the trick. Vorpal turns your Node app into an interactive CLI, and supports extensions including an implementation of the [`less`](https://github.com/vorpaljs/vorpal-less) command in Node.

Something like this would work:

```
var vorpal = require('vorpal')();
var less = require('vorpal-less');

vorpal
  .catch('[commands...]')
  .action(function (args, cb) {
    args.commands = args.commands || [];
    var cmd = args.commands.join(' ');
    var res;
    try {
      res = eval(cmd);
    } catch(e) {
      res = e;
    }
    this.log(res);
    cb();
  });

vorpal
  .delimiter('myrepl>')
  .show();
```

This will turn your application into a REPL within the context of your app, which can also accept the `less` command:

```
$ node myrepl.js
myrepl> 6 * 6 | less

36

: (less prompt)
```

*Disclaimer: I wrote Vorpal*